# Код класса worker.class.php от Mpos

Tags: php, php-frameworks, классы

Сегодня имею желание поинтересоваться:
Как правильно переписать запрос и сделать его автоматическим (добавления в бд юзера автоматом по заданным параметрам с его компа)?
Как выставить значения пароля воркеров в "x" автоматом?

---

P.S. Всю информацию что нужна могу предоставить (формы и дампы бд)

```
  /**
   * Add new worker to an existing web account
   * The webuser name is prefixed to the worker name
   * Passwords are plain text for pushpoold
   * @param account_id int User ID
   * @param workerName string Worker name
   * @param workerPassword string Worker password
   * @return bool
   **/
  public function addWorker($account_id, $workerName, $workerPassword) {
    $this->debug->append("STA " . __METHOD__, 4);
    if ('' === $workerName || '' === $workerPassword) {
      $this->setErrorMessage($this->getErrorMsg('E0058'));
      return false;
    }
    if (!preg_match("/^[0-9a-zA-Z_\-]*$/", $workerName)) {
      $this->setErrorMessage($this->getErrorMsg('E0072'));
      return false;
    }
    $username = $this->user->getUserName($account_id);
    $workerName = "$username.$workerName";
    if (strlen($workerName) > 50) {
      $this->setErrorMessage($this->getErrorMsg('E0073'));
      return false;
    }
    $stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO $this->table (account_id, username, password) VALUES(?, ?, ?)");
    if ($this->checkStmt($stmt) && $stmt->bind_param('iss', $account_id, $workerName, $workerPassword)) {
      if (!$stmt->execute()) {
        if ($stmt->sqlstate == '23000') return $this->sqlError('E0059');
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return $this->sqlError('E0060');
  }
```

[Загрузка класса worker.class.php](https://mega.co.nz/#!md4jRCAb!4OUfVDyRSjxqGCvHAfyBEVKAUpilI5d7ehOK4F0Rq6o)

Comment: @Никита Аристархов, если я правильно понял задачу, то метод вряд ли надо переписывать, надо переписывать (или *дописывать*) то, как он вызывается.

> Как выставить значения пароля воркеров в "x" автоматом?

Достаточно вызывать `addWorker($account_id, $workerName, 'x');`

Comment: а как заделать автопрописывание в БД имя воркера?